# How to raise an XML RPC fault from a PHP server

Tags: php, magento, xml-rpc

I am not a PHP developer. There's some PHP code that is a server which exposes its API via XML RPC.  How do I raise an XML RPC Fault from that code?

**Background**

I am writing a C# client to the PHP XML RPC service. Sometimes, the PHP code bombs off in some layer. When it does, it doesn't send me a XML RPC Fault. In fact, it doesn't even send any XML back. It just sends a plain text string with the message of the exception. I want to edit the PHP code on the server, catch exceptions and make an XML RPC fault to send back to clients.

Answer (score 0):

Raising an XML-RPC fault is really just a matter of outputting the right XML, there's nothing more to it. Depending on the framework you use this might vary, so there's no code I can give you.

Comment: Thank you. I feared as much. Though, I was inclined to think that XML RPC support might have been built into PHP as an intrinsic library that came with the language. Let me find out what those guys at the server end are using.

Comment: There's probably some PHP library that does that, sure, but for some reason the PHP convention often seems to be to write your own library instead of using the default ones.